# Character counter returning incorrect value for char[n] array

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ program for homework, and it needs to count the characters in a char arr[n] string. However, my counter keeps returning the wrong values. I have looked through other answers to similar questions, however, they are not specific to C++ and none of the answers explain the value I am getting.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Counter
{
public:
    char word[20];
    int totChar{ 0 };

    void setWord(char word)
    {
        this->word[20] = word;
    }
    void setCount(int totChar)
    {
        this->totChar = totChar;
    }
    int getLength()
    {
        return totChar;
    }
void charCount()
{
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (word[i] != '\0')
        {
            n++;
        }

    }
    setCount(n);
}
};


int main()
{
    char text[20];
    cout << "Enter the string:" << endl;
    cin >> text;
    Logic input;
    input.setWord(text[20]);
    input.charCount();
    // input.resetWord();
    cout << input.getLength();
}
```

Comment: `this->word[20] = word;`will assign to the ***21:st*** element of the (20-element) array.

Comment: Your program invokes undefined behavior by breaching array boundaries.. Ex: `this->word[20] = word;` and `input.setWord(text[20]);` And it appears you need to review your materials on what constitutes a string, and how zero-based indexing in C++ native arrays work.

Comment: Don't use `string.h` and `stdlib.h` in C++. Use `string` and `cstdlib`. Don't use C-strings. Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: You cannot pass multiple chars using a parameter of type `char`. Using `char` as parameter type results a copy of the char being accessible in the function...

Comment: An example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/BqM6GgC6r1tj4V6x You can use the same code to count the characters in a C-string https://wandbox.org/permlink/GUw6ukOL5ExPPdl2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems you haven't figured out how arrays and C strings work in C++ yet.

```
void setWord(const char* word)
{
    strcpy(this->word, word);
}
```

and

```
Logic input;
input.setWord(text);
```

Your code is a bit weird, I guess you are just experimenting, but I think those two changes should make it work.